# Tablet restarts after entering a game

Tags: applications

My tablet Tesla TTL7 has this problem where when I enter a game or app, it restarts on its own. No other threads have my problem, so I had to make a new one. Anyone had this before? Update: It now only affects games above 1 GB of size. But somehow MKX does not restart my tablet.

Comment: Does that happen for all apps, or just for a specific one? Background: I once had an app that caused exactly that. Replaced it by a similar one, problem gone.

Comment: I never faced this problem. Is the problem happening only for apps that you installed or for all apps including presinstalled apps? And did you install those from a trusted source like playstore or from unknown source?

Comment: All apps are from the play store, the problem only happens when I try to enter Hearthstone and World of Tanks, and also affects games and apps that I freshly installed.

Comment: bumping the post

Comment: Bumpity bumping